# Applying a date format to an input box in Ember using an input helper

Tags: ember.js, momentjs

I have just started using Ember.js and would want to format the date in a bound 
input field to (DD/MM/YYYY) format using the moment.js library. Following the video on the Ember.js website, I did create up a mock application and it is working correctly but with a nagging bug. My date is being formatted correctly in the display but when editing, the input box does not allow me to manually add a date and my binding becomes messed up.

I have banged my head against the keyboard several times and can't find where I am getting it wrong.
[image: in edit mode]

I  have created a  [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/qedawi/3/) here.

Comment: This seems to be an issue with moment parsing years with 3 digits. It will be a lot more easier to solve this using a date picker. Or you may need to some strict parsing with moment js.

Comment: I built this functionality recently using datepicker, as blessenm suggested. My approach was to have a view containing two inputs. 1) A hidden input bound to a property on the controller/model and 2) a second, styled input  bound to a computed property that formats the value of the other input using moment. Such an approach will allow you to keep the model property as a date or moment object but show a user-friendly string in the form. You could use a similar approach here.